# error when call javascript function TypeError: i.contentWindow.hiform is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have two Page 
first page in Main page and contain two frame and Three buttons 
in first frame set src to Second page
after load frame i copy First frame Content into Second Frame and Call a function inside second frame from main page but error *TypeError: i.contentWindow.hiform is not a function*

Main Page Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function CallFunction(frameName)
        {
                var i = document.getElementById(frameName);
                i.contentWindow.hiform();
     }
     function Copy() {
         try {

             var i = document.getElementById('frame1');
             var i2 = document.getElementById('frame2');
             i2.contentWindow.document.body.parentElement.innerHTML = i.contentWindow.document.body.parentElement.innerHTML;
         }
         catch (er) {
             alert(er);
         }
     }
    </script>

<iframe id="frame1" src="Second.aspx" height="100px" width="100%"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame2"  height="100px" width="100%"></iframe>
     <input type="button" id="runFunc" onclick="CallFunction('frame1');" value="Call Function Frame1" /> this work

    <input type="button" id="Copy1" onclick="Copy();"  value="Copy"/>
     <input type="button" id="runFunc2" onclick="CallFunction('frame2');" value="Call Function Frame1" />

</div>
```

Second Page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function hiform() {
        alert('wow');
    }
</script>
<div>
HIIIIIIII
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your first page javascript is not accessible in second page and you need to have a reference of it.
That's why you need to separate the code of javascript and move it to the external file and then reference that file to the second page and then all is well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i can run function from second page but when i copy frame1 to frame2 function not working

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but I wanted to access document in iframe, so this may be helpful:
I solved this by using .contentDocument instead of .contentWindow.document